# Copying the elements of one vector into another

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I need to copy the elements of one vector into another, but in the same process I need to be able to remove the comments or garbage from the data. 
For example; two of the elements are

```
(* Month: 2005 01 *) 31
(* Month: 2005 02 *) 29
```

I need to get rid of the `(* Month: 2005 02 *)`  and just move the `29` into the new vector. I can't seem to figure out how to do this in c++.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service. You have to show what you attempted so far, and explain what is or is not working correctly, and/or what's missing.

Comment: What is the type of the elements of the vector?

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate over the source vector. Then call `push_back()` on the second vector with the appropriate member of each object.

Comment: is it a vector of strings formatted like you showed? Use a regular expression or some other method of string parsing to extract the last number from the string.

Comment: Yes, the data is outputted into a vector of strings. Okay, thank you Barmar! That should help get me started with what I need. 

And Sam, I wasn't asking you to write the code for me. I was asking at how I would go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say

```
string str = "(* Month: 2005 01 *) 31";
```

you can find the last space

```
size_t p = str.find_last_of(" ");
```

then extract the substring you're interested in

```
string sub_str = str.substr(p+1)
```